# matlab genetic algorithm stopping criterion maximum number of function evaluations

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, genetic-algorithm

I am using genetic algorithm function

```
ga(fitnessfcn,nvars,.....,options)
```

where we can set various parameters for the algorithms using `gaoptimset(...)`.
However, I am not able to understand how to set *maximum number of objective function evaluations* as the stopping criterion for this function.

I found the parameter `Generations` for stopping criterion, but it sets only the maximum number of generations and each generation has more than one function evaluations.

So, can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about a standard genetic algorithm, let's say you have a population of N chromosomes. In each generation, the fitness of each antibody is calculated by calling the evaluation function. So, for G generations, the total number of function evaluations in G*N. So, instead of setting the number of function evaluations, set the number of generations to

G = (desired number of function evaluations) / (population size)

The number of function evaluations is usually used in comparisons instead of the number of generations because:

- Different algorithms perform different number of function evaluations per generation. For example, immune systems create C clones for each antibody and evaluate the clones, so the number of function evaluations is G*N*C
- The evaluation function is usually by far the most computationally expensive part of the algorithm.

Comment: but not all the chromosomes from previous generation survive to the next generation. So, this formula doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Even if some chromosomes are rejected, they are still evaluated. Since the size of the population remains constant, N chromosomes are evaluated in every generation.

Comment: In my case I've found the solution in 6 generations but `funccount` is 675 which means the function was evaluated 675 times even though I've found the solution in 6 generations. How would that be possible?